# How to move cursor position using match expressions in F#?

Tags: f#, expression, match

I thought it would make more sense to use match expressions in F# rather than while loops and if statements, but I can't get it to work. The code looks fine to me and I get no errors. Could somebody explain why it doesn't work, please?

```
open System

let width  = Console.WindowWidth
let height = Console.WindowHeight

let rec main() =
    let x = Console.CursorLeft
    let y = Console.CursorTop
    match Console.ReadKey().Key with
    | ConsoleKey.UpArrow    -> Console.SetCursorPosition(x, (y - 1))
    | ConsoleKey.RightArrow -> Console.SetCursorPosition((x + 1), y)
    | ConsoleKey.DownArrow  -> Console.SetCursorPosition(x, (y + 1))
    | ConsoleKey.LeftArrow  -> Console.SetCursorPosition((x - 1), y)
    | _ -> main()
    main()

Console.ReadKey() |> ignore
```

Comment: What do you mean by "it doesn't work"? There are far too many possible behaviors covered by that phrase; we won't be able to tell you *why* it doesn't work until you give us more details about *how* it doesn't work: that is, *what* you expected to happen that isn't happening. Also, why do you have that `_ -> main()` call? You're going to call `main()` again one line later; is it really your intent to call `main()` twice if the user presses the `A` key or something?

Comment: @rmunn I'm trying to make the cursor move position but it does not, and I didn't know I didn't need a '_ ->'. It leaves a green line under 'Console.ReadKey().Key' which is annoying. When I run it, it closes after I press a key instead of allowing me to continuously move the cursor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem you're having is that after defining the `main()` function, you don't ever call it.

Here's what your code looks like right now:

```
let rec main() =
    // The definition of main()

Console.ReadKey() |> ignore
```

Remember that in F#, indentation is significant: after a `let someName =` declaration, the rest of the next indented block is the body of the function. So there are just *two* top-level expressions in your code: one that defines a function called `main()` that is never called, and another one that reads a key from the console. In F#, there's nothing special about naming a function `main()`. To make a function the entry point to your program (the first thing to be run when your program is run), [you need to declare it with the `EntryPoint` attribute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fsharp/language-reference/functions/entry-point):

```
[<EntryPoint>]
let rec main() =
    // The definition of main()
```

Also take note of what the docs say about implicit entry points:

> When a program has no `EntryPoint` attribute that explicitly indicates the entry point, the top level bindings in the last file to be compiled are used as the entry point.

The "top level bindings" in the program that you've shown us do two things: define a function, then read a key.

Put the `EntryPoint` attribute before your `let rec main() =` line and I suspect that will fix your problem. Or if you're running this as an `.fsx` script, then `[<EntryPoint>]` isn't the right approach, and you instead need to put a call to `main()` in the top-level part of the program (after it's been defined).

Comment: Thanks, this help a lot. Not sure how I forgot to actually call the function... If I put the EntryPoint before let rec main() = it doesn't work, I get an error in main(). But if I do it below then call to the function inside the EntryPoint it works perfectly!